# web guard allows login but admin guard does not allow login

Tags: laravel, eloquent, controller, guard, laravel-middleware

I define a new guard "Admin" to have a multi Auth System User and admin in my project . web guard allows login.But  admin guard does not allow login
when I try to login into Admin ,it gives

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'last_sign_in_at' in 'field list' (SQL: update `admins` set `updated_at` = 2020-09-27 12:49:24, `last_sign_in_at` = 2020-09-27 12:49:24, `current_sign_in_at` = 2020-09-27 12:49:24 where `id` = 1)
```

My users table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('user_type');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
        $table->timestamp('last_sign_in_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('current_sign_in_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('user_click');
        $table->timestamp('user_click_time')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My admin table

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('user_type');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();

             });
    }
```

auth.php

```
  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        //admin guard
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],





 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],



 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

My Middleware **CheckRole**

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        
        if (!Auth::guard('admin')->check()){
            return redirect('admin/login');
        }
        return $next($request);
        
    }
```

My  **Admin.php** Model

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
//guard
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
//guard End

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{

    use Notifiable;
    protected $guard ='admin';
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    protected $guarded=[];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];


}
```

My **AdminController**

```
   public function adminLogin(Request $request){
        if ($request->ismethod('post')) {
            $data = $request->input();

            if ( Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => $data['password'],
                'user_type'=>'admin', 'status' => '1'])){
                return view('admin.dashboard');
            }
            else {

                return back()->with('error',' Invalid UserName Or Password');
            }

        }

    }
```

When I tried to login into Admin, It gives error. Any solution ps !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have an event listener listening for Auth's LoginEvent and it is setting the `last_sign_in_at` field on the Model and saving it. Since you are using different models for Authentication it will end up trying to do this on what ever Model is in that event; in this case the Admin model.

You will need to add this field to your admin table, or you will have to check in the listener which Model the event is holding and decide whether to update this field depending on what type that model is.

Comment: If I remove listeners ,then it will be ok ?

Comment: so you are asking "if the listener is causing the problem, if i remove it will it no longer cause the problem that it causes?"  :-)

Comment: did you even try what you asked?